# Keep Operator Properties popup expanded

Tags: customization

How do I keep the operator properties pop up menu expanded by default?

[image]

I'd like to make it open by default, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This setting is saved with the startup file preferences.

On a blank startup file just use some operator (like say *Add > Plane*) and expand the operator options panel once (you can delete the object or undo afterwards if you like).

After expanding the panel go to *File > Defaults > Save Startup File* and next time you call any operator with options it will be expanded.

[image]

Since this is saved in the startup file, it should be available in all new Blender sessions as well.

Comment: Thanks! the only issue is that it works per workspace and per editor so you need to do it  in each of them.