# Keep Custom Operator (created by python API) properties expanded/open by default

Tags: python, properties, operator

My question is exactly the same as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169217/keep-operator-properties-popup-expanded?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C74.4571), except it is for a custom-created operator using the python API. I would like to know how to programmatically keep the properties popup expanded.

Background: In my Addon, I can invoke the operator in a few different ways. One way, is by explicitly clicking on a button in the panel stating "edit". It is for that particular use-case that I want to force the properties to be expanded. Otherwise, the user may not see the tiny interface element that popped up in response to clicking "edit".

Comment: Maybe you want to explore the [invoke](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#invoke-function) method that can be used to open an unmistakable popup near the cursor ? with https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog or https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_popup

Comment: That worked. Not directly out of the box, but nearly. thanks