# Can I change Blender to always show certain panels or menus?

Tags: interface

is there a way to make the popup window expanded when adding new geometry?

[image: Add Plane]

And the same or similar thing with the Item window on the top right in the 3D viewport.
Can I have that always visible?
[image: Item]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169223/19307

Answer (score 2):

The popup window should stay expanded for subsequent operations once you've initially expanded it. There's no specific setting to keep it expanded.

For the items on the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, right-click on the double dotted line on the Item panel (1) then check the <kbd>Pin</kbd> checkbox (2) to keep it visible. You can also drag the item up and down on the panel to position it once it's pinned and left-click on the pin to unpin it.

[image]