# How do I turn on snapping for node editors by default?

Tags: node-editor, snapping

I really like to keep my nodes snapped to the grid. I am a psychopath about it. But one thing that I hate is that I have to manually turn on snapping everytime I open Blender. Is there any way to keep it on by default?

Comment: Save it in the startup file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169217/keep-operator-properties-popup-expanded